# Backpack for Laravel with Relationship giving an errort

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-backpack

I have a table of countries and a table of continents. The countries has a field "continent_id". The Country model has a method:

```
public function getContinent()
      {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Continent','continent_id','id');
      }
```

and if I test this with tinker I get the right response:

```
$co = App\Models\Country::with('getContinent)->first()
```

[image]

In my setup on CountryCrudController I want to add a field that shows the continent - and I will also want to add a selection of the 7 continents to the countries edit, so in the list part I defined:

```
  $this->crud->addColumn([
      'name' => "continent",
      'label' => "continent", // Table column heading
      'type' => "select",
      'entity' => 'getContinent ', // the method in your Model
      'attribute' => 'continent',
    ]);
```

but when I try to run it I get:

[image]

What I am doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

**You have a space after getContinent** - that definitely shouldn't be there.

Also, the **name** of the field should be the column in the database, so you name should be **continent_id**, not **continent**.

```
  $this->crud->addColumn([
      'name' => "continent_id",
      'label' => "Continent", // Table column heading
      'type' => "select",
      'entity' => 'getContinent', // the method in your Model
      'attribute' => 'continent',
    ]);
```

I'm pretty sure it'll work with the above.